# django postgres reload dump error

Tags: django, postgresql

Please can any one tell me why i get this message

```
DatabaseError: Could not load contenttypes.ContentType(pk=10): permission denied for relation django_content_type
```

recently dumped my database to a file now I want to reload it back I get an error like the one above what dose it mean and dose one know why I am getting this error and how can I correct it and what dose this error mean?

Answer (score 1):

Generally permission denied errors like that are caused by having a DB user who does not have access to the given table. Are you sure that your user has access? When you sign on under your django user's credentials, what happens when you try to `select * from django_contenttypes` (unsure of table name, if not that, then django_contenttype_contenttype maybe)?

Comment: i get this ERROR:  relation "django_contenttypes" does not exist